# ratio score in difflib

Tags: python, difflib

I am trying to understand how the ratio in difflib work

```
s = SequenceMatcher("private","privateT")
    for opcode in s.get_opcodes():
          print "%6s a[%d:%d] b[%d:%d]" % opcode
```

> delete a[0:8] b[0:0]

```
print (s.ratio()*100)
```

> 93.3

as I know from [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/difflib.html#difflib.SequenceMatcher.ratio)

`T` means a total of number and `M` matches characters

my first question what `2.0` referred to?

```
(2.0*7/15)*100
93.3
```

also in `get_opcodes`, for edit the word there is equal, replace and delete.

my second question does any of them affect the ratio score?